# Solve recurrence relation $a_n=-na_{n-1}+n!$ with $a_{0}=1$

Tags: combinatorics

> Solve recurrence relation $$a_n=-na_{n-1}+n!$$ with $a_{0}=1$.

I can solve the relation using generating function as well as by using theory of differential equations . But the problem here is the term $n!$. 
Please suggest me method and proper way to solve this relation.

Comment: Have you tried computing the first few values to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. For $n\geq 1$,
$$a_{n+1}=-(n+1)a_{n}+(n+1)!=-(n+1)(-na_{n-1}+n!)+(n+1)!=(n+1)na_{n-1}.$$
Therefore
$$a_{n+1}=(n+1)(n)a_{n-1}=(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-3}=\dots=(n+1)!a_{r}$$
where $r=0$ if $n$ is odd and $r=1$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: That means now we can solve the recurrence relation obtained as above with $a_1=1$ instead of original relation.

Comment: Solve the recurrence relation by finding $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ separately.

Comment: Sorry but how solving separately will help ?

Comment: I edited my answer. See if it helps.